# In /var/log/messages, how do you tell if a connection started or finished?

Tags: networking, log

How can one differentiate between the start of a network connect and the end of one, from the logs listed in `/var/log/messages`?

All the logs look identical.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? A few log files, including this one, are named differently in different versions. (Please **edit your post** to include this information...then you can flag this comment as obsolete.)

Comment: @EliahKagan @Ian Or to phrase it another way, in Ubuntu 12.04 desktop I get the following error message: `ls: cannot access /var/logs/messages: No such file or directory`. Please provide more information about what, exactly, you are asking about.

Comment: @irrationalJohn It should actually be `/var/log/messages`, I neglected to notice that error in the question when I edited it originally. Anyway, `/var/log/dmesg` used to be called `/var/log/messages`, on older versions of Ubuntu (e.g., 10.04 LTS). I think it's still useful to have the release version in the question, though.

Comment: @EliahKagan Definitely need more information. There is no way to provide an "answer" to the question as it is currently asked.

Comment: Indeed. Ian, please also add specific lines taken from your `/var/log/messages` file to your question, so it's clear exactly what you're asking and exactly why it's unclear if they are describing connection or disconnection.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu Server 12.04, that information usually goes to `/var/log/syslog`. 
I have intentionally unplugged a ethernet card on a server and connected it back, I got this:

```
Jun  6 20:16:34 tagua kernel: [ 4416.930972] r8169 0000:01:06.0: eth0: link down
Jun  6 20:16:34 tagua kernel: [ 4416.932817] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Jun  6 20:19:09 tagua kernel: [ 4571.990507] r8169 0000:01:06.0: eth0: link up
Jun  6 20:19:09 tagua kernel: [ 4571.991172] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

If I run `sudo ifdown eth0` the output is (among other lines):

```
Jun  6 20:28:05 tagua NetworkManager[1295]:  (eth0): carrier now OFF (device state 10)
```

When I reactivate it with `sudo ifup eth0`

```
Jun  6 20:28:23 tagua NetworkManager[1295]:  (eth0): carrier now ON (device state 10)
```